# Let $X$ be a connected metric space and $A, B \subset X$ Show that $d(x,A) = d(x,B)$ doesn't hold without the connectedness assumption.

Tags: metric-spaces, connectedness

> Let $X$ be a connected metric space and $A, B \subset X$ non-empty sets. (i) Show that there exists $x \in X$ such that $d(x,A) = d(x,B).$ (ii) Give an example that shows that (i) doesn't work without the connectedness.

For (i) let $f(x)=d(x,A)-d(x,B)$. Now if $A\cap B \ne \emptyset$, then there is $x \in A\cap B$ for which $f(x) = d(x, A) - d(x, B) = 0 \implies d(x,A)=d(x,B)$. So assume that $A\cap B = \emptyset$. Then there exists $a \in A$ for which $d(a,A) =0$ So $f(a)=d(a,A)-d(a,B)= -d(a,B) \le 0$. Similarly $b \in B$ such that $d(b,B) = 0$ so $f(b) =d(b,A) \ge  0$ so there is an $x \in X$ for which $f(x) = 0$ and $d(x,A) =d(x,B)$.

Now I cannot find an example that would satisfy (ii) any tips on how should I approach this part of the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take, for instance, $X=\{-1,1\}$ (endowed with the usual distance), $A=\{-1\}$, and $B=\{1\}$.

Comment: So now $x \in X$ is either $-1$ or $1$, but how can I even talk about the diameter of $A$ or $B$ since they're singletons?

Comment: What has your questions to do with diameters?

Comment: Sorry I got confused. It seems that either case if $x = -1$ then $d(x,A) = 0 \ne d(x,B) = 2$ of if $x = 1$, then $d(x,A) = 2 \ne 0 = d(x,B)$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.